# When i change the value of an multidimensional array, the value at the same position of another array changes too. Why?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

It took me much time to even only figure this out.

I have 2 multidimensional arrays:

```
int[,] OldGeneration = new int[WidthX + 1, HeightY + 1];
int[,] NextGeneration = new int[WidthX + 1, HeightY + 1];
```

Later in my Code after I set some values in "NextGeneration" i make the arrays contain the same.

```
OldGeneration = NextGeneration;
```

When I check the values while running the program its working.

A bit below then i change one value of "NextGeneration and when i do that, the same value in "OldGeneration" will be changed as well.

Can you tell me why?

```
using System;

namespace CGoL
{
    class CGoL_Base
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declare and define (initialize) Variables used by the Program
            int WidthX = 5, HeightY = 5, Iterations = 5, Speed = 1000, Random = 0, CellsAlive = 0;

            //Declare Multidimensional Arrays for actual generation and next generation
            int[,] OldGeneration = new int[WidthX + 1, HeightY + 1];
            int[,] NextGeneration = new int[WidthX + 1, HeightY + 1];


            //###########   Initialize "Game Board"   ##########################

            //Set Game Board to contain only dead cells
            for (int y = 1; y <= HeightY; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 1; x <= WidthX; x++)
                {
                    NextGeneration[x, y] = 0;
                }
            }

            //Set pattern for oscillating (moving) structure with 3 living cells (Can be changed at will)
            NextGeneration[3, 2] = 1;
            NextGeneration[3, 3] = 1;
            NextGeneration[3, 4] = 1;

            //Set OldGeneration equal with NextGeneration so that the calculation can work
            OldGeneration = NextGeneration;

            //##################################################################

            //Start the iterationcounter
            for (int Iteration = 1; Iteration <= Iterations; Iteration++)
            {
                //###########   Calculate actual generation   ######################
                //Calculate how the Game Board will change with the usual CGoL rules

                if (Iteration >= 2) //Without this, the initialization above will not work
                {
                    for (int y = 1; y <= HeightY; y++)
                    {
                        for (int x = 1; x <= WidthX; x++)
                        {
                            //###########   Check surrounding Cells   ##########################
                            //Check how much cells, surrounding the actual cell, are still alive
                            //to calculate later how the Game Board will change

                            CellsAlive = 0;

                            for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
                            {
                                for (int n = -1; n <= 1; n++)
                                {

                                    if (i == 0 && n == 0)
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }

                                    //Check if some Array Index will be out of Array Range (for example when index is smaller than 0)
                                    if (x + n == 0 || x + n > WidthX || y + i == 0 || y + i > HeightY)
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    if (OldGeneration[(x + n), (y + i)] == 1)
                                    {
                                        CellsAlive++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            //##################################################################

                            //If a dead cell got 3 living neighbours, the cell will become alive in the next generation
                            if (OldGeneration[x, y] == 0 && CellsAlive == 3)
                            {
                                NextGeneration[x, y] = 1;
                            }
                            //If a living cell got less than 2 living neighbours, the cell will die in the next generation
                            else if (OldGeneration[x, y] == 1 && CellsAlive < 2)
                            {
                                NextGeneration[x, y] = 0; //OldGeneration[x, y] will be changed to 0 even if it is not written here????? why?
                            }
                            //If a living cell got 2 or 3 living neighbours, the cell will stay alive in the next generation
                            else if (OldGeneration[x, y] == 1 && (CellsAlive == 2 || CellsAlive == 3))
                            {
                                NextGeneration[x, y] = 1;
                            }
                            //If a living cell got more than 3 living neighbours, the cell will die in the next generation
                            else if (OldGeneration[x, y] == 1 && CellsAlive > 3)
                            {
                                NextGeneration[x, y] = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                //##################################################################

                //###########   Draw the "Game Board"   ############################

                //Makes the console window Empty :)

                Console.Clear();

                //"for" is making new rows with Console.Write("\n");
                for (int y = 1; y <= HeightY; y++)
                {
                    //"for" is writing "O"'s in one row
                    for (int x = 1; x <= WidthX; x++)
                    {
                        if (NextGeneration[x, y] == 1)
                        {
                            Console.Write("O ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("  ");
                        }
                    }
                    Console.Write("\n");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Iteration: {0}", Iteration);

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Speed);

                //At the end, make the actual generation same like the old generation to be calculated next
                OldGeneration = NextGeneration;

                //##################################################################
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you state:

```
OldGeneration = NextGeneration;
```

You're assigning a reference of NextGeneration to OldGeneration so it's normal that any change you do to  one will also reflect to the other.

If you want to make a disjoint copy, you should use `Array.Copy` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/y5s0whfd(v=vs.110).aspx )

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem: `OldGeneration = NextGeneration;`

Before this line you had two objects (two arrays), and after it you have one object that both variables look at. Instead of the line above you must copy the content in a double loop.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not making the arrays contain the same values, you replace the reference of one array with the reference to the other array.

From that point, both variables reference the same array. When you change the array using one variable, the change will be visible when you look at the array using the other variable, because it's the same array.

If you want to copy the data from one array to another, you can use the [`Array.Copy` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Array.Copy(NextGeneration, OldGeneration, NextGeneration.Length);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked for me. Usually im working with hashes in Perl and there it is working to make them "same". Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using this line:

```
OldGeneration = NextGeneration;
```

You make the `OldGeneration` variable to reference the same memory as the `NextGeneration` variable.

You could copy the array instead:

```
Array.Copy(NextGeneration, OldGeneration, NextGeneration.Length);
```

Comment: This is not working. It tells then that it is only working for onedimensional arrays.